# Cache control max-age 0 vs missing max-age

Tags: caching, max-age

I have a quick question.

Is a missing max-age the same as a max-age=0 with the cache-control header?

I can't find any relative documentation regarding a missing max-age directive.

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Browser caching request/response without any Cache-Control header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62838739/browser-caching-request-response-without-any-cache-control-header)